# create auto generated id when view loads or app launches in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to create a auto generated id when app launches or when a view loads. For instance, i launch the app and id 1000 should be created. Next time i launch the app 1001 should be created and so on. How can i achieve this? Any Suggestions?

Comment: You should probably think about using a database or user defaults. What have you tried so far, can you post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the following code to your viewDidLoad: method

```
if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"id"] )
{
   int previousId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]intForKey:@"id"];
   previousId++;
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInt:previousId forKey:@"id"];
}
else
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInt:1000 forKey:@"id"]; //set initial id on first launch
}
```

If the key id is present in user defaults, this code will increment the id by 1, and if it is not present(first launch of App), it will initialise it to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Store your value in userdefaults and nexttime when you launch the app, read the id value from user default and then increment it by 1 and again set the same.

**Note :- This will only work only for individual user not for all users, or else save the id value into database server and then there make the change and save it**

Comment: say i store the value like below in view did load

Comment: NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefault setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000] forKey:@"incident#"];

This code will execute everytime when view loads. So everytime the value will be 1000 right?

Comment: No before that you can put the contion using objectfor key if value exist then increment accordingly and then set it